# Open "Folder Options" dialog programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

Exists any way to open "Folder Options" (In windows Explorer: Tools > Folder Options) dialog programmatically? If no, how to set "Show hidden files and folders"? Sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
       FileName = "RUNDLL32.EXE",
       Arguments = "shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 0"
   };
Process.Start(psi);
```

There is a quite extensive reference here: [Dx21 RunDLL32](http://dx21.com/coding/libraries/rundll32/default.aspx).

Comment: awsome didn't know you could do that :D